# Why $ f $ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$X$ = $\mathbb{R}^n$  and

$f:X \times X \rightarrow X$

$($x$ , $y$) \rightarrow x+y$

This is for addition on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but why  here $f$ can be continuous?

Comment: Try to follow the definition.

Comment: Because it is?  Do you know what the definition of continuous is?  Can you apply to definition?  If not, why not?  Where do you start to have trouble?

Comment: Are $X$ and $X \times X$ being considered as a metric spaces? If so, for what distances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you constructed two metric spaces $(X, d)$ and $(X*X, d')$ where $d'(u,v)=d'((u_1, u_2),(v_1,v_2))=\sqrt{d(u_1,v_1)^2+d(u_2,v_2)^2}$ for every $u,v \in X*X$.

For every sequence $\{ (x_n,y_n) \}$ that $(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow (x,y) $ in $X*X$ we have $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$ in $X$, which implies that $f(x_n,y_n)=x_n+y_n\rightarrow x+y=f(x,y)$.

I hope my answer will help you well.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to conclude that $f$ is continuous on $X*X$

Comment: you can use \times for $\times$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $(E, \| \|)$ is a normed vector space, $f$ is  Lipschitz continuous: in fact, if $(x_1, y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in E\times E$, where we consider the following distance on $E\times E$
$$ d( (x_1, y_1),(x_2,y_2))= \|x_1 -x_2 \| + \|y_1-y_2\| $$
then
$$ \|f(x_1, y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)\| = \|x_1+y_1-(x_2+y_2)\| = \| (x_1-x_2) + (y_1 -y_2)\| \leq \| (x_1-x_2) \| + \| (y_1 -y_2)\|= d( (x_1, y_1),(x_2,y_2)).$$
Hence, $f$ is $1-$Lipschitz continuous which implies continuity.